# Do I need to use AsQueryable() for a method that returning IQueryable<Type> in .NET EF

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq

I am working on a ASP.NET project. For interacting with database, I am using Entity Framework and LINQ. What I know is using `IQueryable` is better than `IEnumerable`  If another query is going to be performed. But what I am wondering is, I have a repository and a method as below:

```
public IQueryable<Category> getData(){ return db.categories.AsQueryable(); }
```

As you can see above, I am doing type casting using AsQueryable in return statement whereas the function return type is IQueryable already. But I am doing it because I am not sure, if I call that function in Controller like `repository.getData()`, will it be `IQueryable` without type casting?

Can I remove `AsQueryable()` type casting? Without it, will it be converted to `IEnumerable`? Will that offer the same performance if I remove `AsQueryable`?

Comment: The simplest way to find out is to run code without `AsQuerable()` method.

Comment: Then I can I inspect performance?

Comment: In what aspect? As Can Pouyrazoglu mentioned in His answer, if `db.categories` is `IQuerable<Category>`, then `AsQuerable()` method is redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `db.categories` is derived from (or simply is) `IQueryable<Category>` then yeah, sure, you can remove it.

Comment: A more solid answer would be that `db.categories`'s type is `DbSet<Category>` (no reason to assume otherwise) and hence *is* `IQueryable<Category>`.